# Trying to get a plot using Seaborn but Error saying 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

train = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
# Extract data on column "Category" from train data
Cates = train["Category"].unique()
figure, ax = plt.subplots(10,4)

for i in range(len(Cates)):
    a = train[train['Category']==Cates[i]]
    sns.countplot(data=each, x="DayOfWeek", ax=ax[(i//4)][i%4])
```

Comment: Have you tried `x=train["DayOfWeek"]`?

Comment: you wrote `sns.countplot(data=each, ...` what is `each`?